# How to escape newlines with "\" using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

The goal is to split a string into lines, except when preceded by a backslash. Let's visualise. A string like this:

```
Hello\
 world!
Bye, world.
```

should be split:

```
[0] Hello world!
[1] Bye, world!
```

I've come up with this regex (for PHP, `preg_split`):

```
/(?<!\\\\)\n/
```

It splits and takes backslashes into account when splitting, but:

- Backslash and newline characters persist.
- It only works with UNIX-like newlines (`\n`).

So, it actually outputs:

```
[0] Hello\\x10 world!
[1] Bye, world!
```

How should my regex look like?

So far, to solve the issues, I've tried:

```
/(?<!\\\\)(?:\r\n|\n|\r)/
/(?:(?<!\\\\)\n)/
```

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps:

1. Join the lines
2. Then split

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\\\\\)*)\\\\((?:\n|\r)+)/', "$1", $text);
$result = preg_split('/(\r|\n)+/', $text);
```

The first regex makes sure it only splits when there is an odd number of slashes before the newline, so an "escaped slash" is preserved.

Because of this, you might consider replacing the escaped backslashes with real ones at the end:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\\\\\)*)\\\\((?:\n|\r)+)/', "$1", $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\\\\\\\\(?=(\\\\\\\\)*$)/m', '\\', $text);
$result = preg_split('/\r\n?|\n/', $text);
```

Comment: I think even with `''` you need `\\\\ ` for a single backslash. And in the replacement string you can use `$1`.

Comment: @m.buettner So it would seem. PHP just complained on me :P

Comment: *preg_replace(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 27*

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt to fix the problem is already quite good. But you will not get rid of the line breaks with the same regex that does the splitting. You could use this `preg_replace` on your input first (to eliminate the escaped line breaks):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\(?:\r\n?|\n)/', '', $str);
```

Then do a simple `preg_split` with:

```
$result = preg_split('/\r\n?|\n/', $str);
```

Note: you might want to be a bit more forgiving with the position of the backslash, so that trailing whitespace at the end of a line is ignored. That would make the initial replacement look like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\[ \t]*(?:\r\n?|\n)/', '', $str);
```

Now an accidental tab or space at the end of a line (after a backslash) does not break the escaping.